# Issue with how Tkinter is storing extracted text into a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter and Python. Currently, the program is extracting and outputting the text into the GUI how it's supposed to. The problem is that I'm trying to store the extracted text into the "page_stuff" variable. When I do this, it does not work how it's supposed to. For example, if I have 2 pages in the PDF that are being extracted, only the second page gets stored in the variable page_stuff.

Here is my code. This is my first time using Tkinter so I would appreciate any feedback on how to fix the problem of storing my text into a variable. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated as well. Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import END

!pip install PyPDF2
import PyPDF2

root = Tk()
#GUI title
root.title('Input PDF')
#GUI size
root.geometry('500x500')

#Text box
my_text = Text(root, height = 30, width = 60)
my_text.pack(pady = 10)

#clears text box
def clear_text_box():
    my_text.delete(1.0, END)

#opens pdf
def open_pdf():
    global page_stuff
    open_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir = "C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Documents/PDF's",
        title = "Open PDF FIle",
        filetypes = (
             ("PDF Files", "*.pdf"),
            ("All Files", "*.*")
        )
    )        
    
    if open_file: 
        pdf_file = PyPDF2.PdfReader(open_file)
            
        all_pages_text = ""
            
        for page_num in range(len(pdf_file.pages)):
        
            page = pdf_file.pages[page_num]
        
            page_stuff = page.extract_text()
    
            my_text.insert(END, page_stuff)

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = my_menu)

#Menu settings 
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff = FALSE)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="open", command = open_pdf)
file_menu.add_command(label="clear", command = clear_text_box)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="exit", command = root.quit)

#Runs GUI
root.mainloop()

#page_stuff saved as variable
display(page_stuff)
```

Comment: Every time you do `page_stuff = page.extract_text()`, you are in effect saying "throw out the old page_stuff and replace it with this new information".

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you! @BryanOakley